# How to find common values of two variables of different length?

Tags: sas

I'm very new to SAS. I spent some time looking for a solution for my problem. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any. I'd very much appreciate your help. The problem is actually quite simple.

I have two different datasets (let's call it dat1 and dat2) of different length. Moreover, they both have a variable X, which I'm interested in. I'm looking for a way to find common values of these two columns (let's call them dat1_X and dat2_X). The dataset is quite big though, approximately 10 million observations.

Comment: Please give examples of your data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Look into proc compare.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways!

If one dataset was small, and efficiency was an issue, you could consider using hash tables (or formats) to perform a lookup whilst passing through the larger one.

Otherwise, the following SQL approaches will do the trick (try testing to see which is most efficient):

```
/* correlated subquery (generally slow) */
proc sql;
create table want1 as
  select distinct x 
  from dat1_x
  where x in (select from dat2_x);

/* inner join */
proc sql;
create table want2 as
  select distinct a.x
  from dat1_x a, dat2_x b
  where a.x=b.x;

/* intersect */
proc sql;
create table want3 as
  select x 
  from dat1_x
intersect
  select x
  from dat2_x;
```